# What dataypes should the columns in a table belong to?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table in a database,am creating columns as below,names and sample data are
 below,can anyone provide suggestion on what datatypes should these belong to?

```
1.
SI:
LNX.LA.0.0
CNSS_SW.RM.1.0
.....

2.
COMPONENT:

US_COMPONENT_TB_FM_BLUEfox64
US_COMPONENT_FC_BLUEfox64
....

3.
US_VERSION:
00.00.0086
00.01.008
......
```

Comment: there's only so many datatypes to choose from. pick something and go. about all we can tell you is "varchar", since none of those samples are purely numeric and very obviously not date/time-related.

Comment: VARCHAR() would make the most sense since these are obviously not a date, or number or any other standard type. Since they differ in length from one record to the next VARCHAR would be better than CHAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your unsure fill it and try

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/procedure-analyse.html